# I have been using this on edit function for about 7 months and it has worked perfect

Tags: google-apps-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNI8w.png)

I haven't made any changes to my google spreadsheet, but now when I try to add criteria in column F it fails to drop the cell down.

When I go into the script editor and hit run I get this error message.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:3

Any thoughts as to what may have happened?

I made sure the name of the sheet is still "Sheet 1"

Comment: Running a [simple trigger function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) from the editor won't work because it won't provide a value for the `e` parameter. If you go to the "Executions" tab, you should be able to find logs that may contain a different error that is occuring when the script automatically runs after spreadsheet edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1  && e.value != "") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,6).copyTo(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```